# Python : How to avoid numpy RuntimeWarning in function definition?

Tags: python, numpy

i designed a simple function to return a mathematical function which can be used to fit experimental data to it. The functions looks pretty much like the following:

```
def colecole_2(f,*p):
    term1=p[0] * ( 1 - 1 / (1 + numpy.power((0+1j) * 2 * numpy.pi * f * p[1], p[2])))
    term2=p[3] * ( 1 - 1 / (1 + numpy.power((0+1j) * 2 * numpy.pi * f * p[4], p[5])))
    return p[6]*(1-abs( term1+ term2))
```

Unfortunately I run into troubles with RunTimeWarnings as:

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in power
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in divide
```

due to values that are too large or small. I am not able to figure this problem out on my own though. Is there any way to redefine my function so it will pass without warnings?

Comment: Do you know how to catch exceptions?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski, These weren't raised.

Comment: @MikeGraham:  My bad.  I misunderstood your question *and* missed that they were warnings.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `numpy.seterr` to control what numpy does in this circumstance: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html

Use the warnings module to control how warnings are or are not presented: http://docs.python.org/library/warnings.html

Comment: To ignore as given in the warnings.html reference.import warnings
def fxn():
    warnings.warn("deprecated", DeprecationWarning)
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    fxn()

Answer (score 53):

You can use [numpy.errstate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.errstate.html#numpy.errstate) which is a built-in context manager.  This will let you set the err handing to be within the context of the with statement.

```
import numpy
# warning is not logged here. Perfect for clean unit test output
with numpy.errstate(divide='ignore'):
    numpy.float64(1.0) / 0.0
```

I had to do this recently when writing unit tests for some legacy python code.

Comment: This sets the division output to inf whereas, without context, the division result is nan.

Answer (score 5):

To go around this, you could increase the precision by modifying the type of the array elements on which you call your function.

For example, if multiplying array  **a**  with large numbers as elements by a large floating point number raises an exception

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply
```

then upon specifying the following

```
a = np.array(a, dtype=np.float128)
```

no warning occurs.

Comment: From version 1.23 documentation: In spite of the names, np.float96 and np.float128 provide only as much precision as np.longdouble, that is, 80 bits on most x86 machines and 64 bits in standard Windows builds. So you could use np.longdouble