# How to make PyCharm to break on Runtime warning?

Tags: pycharm

I have encountered "RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp ..." in my code. How do I make pyCharm break on this warning? It currently runs past it.

Comment: Are you using numpy? You could make it raise an exception instead and find out where. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519237/python-how-to-avoid-runtimewarning-in-function-definition or http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html

Answer (score 31):

I did my own research and similarly to what @doctorlove said, do

```
numpy.seterr(all='raise')
```

then numpy will raise exceptions instead of RuntimeWarnings. The exceptions can then be caught by PyCharm.

Comment: I take it you didn't find a better solution to this problem? Because breakpoints stop the application, where as I would like to have it break but able to continue...

Comment: @shadow The exception can be caught manually since you can localize it in your code using the debugger.

Answer (score 8):

You can use warning module to turn the warning into an error, then try-except and set break point:

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter('error')
try:
   #code that generates warning
except:
   #put a breakpoint here
```

Comment: How do you remove it later? I want to catch warnings only in a specific block. I wish to add something like warnings.simplefilter('') after the except section