# Numpy method of returning values based on two different arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two NumPy arrays, say num and denom. I need to return specific values, based on if the respective elements are zero or not, in num and denom,

```
        r2 = []
        for denind, denel in enumerate(denom):
            numel = num[denind]
            if denel:  # Denominator is not zero
                r2.append(1 - numel/denom)
            elif numel:  # Denominator is zero, but numerator is not zero
                r2.append(0.0)
            else:  # Both denominator and numerator are zero.
                r2.append(1.0)
        return np.array(r2)
```

Is there a "NumPy" way of doing such an iteration.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've edited it, by the way, numel is used in the `if numel` condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about doing the minimal amount of division work?

```
r2 = np.ones_like(numel, dtype=float)
num_mask = (numel != 0)
den_mask = (denel != 0)
mask = num_mask & den_mask
r2[mask] = 1 - numel[mask]/denel[mask]
mask = ~den_mask & num_mask
r2[mask] = 0
```

Comment: This seems really elegant to me. Is there any difference if I do, `r2 = np.ones(numel.shape[1], dtype=float)` in the first line?

Comment: No, but `ones_like` saves you having to extract the shape of the array manually.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use a boolean array as an index to fix up an array after your division.  And you can use `isinf(a)` and `isnan(a)` to get the desired boolean arrays for indexing `a`.

```
with numpy.errstate(divide='ignore'):
    res = 1.0 - num/double(den);
res[isinf(res)] = 0.0;   # zero denominator will give +- infinity
res[isnan(res)] = 1.0;   # both zero will give nan
```

The magic here is that the boolean-array index returns a view into `res` which only selects those elements for which the boolean was `True`.  If you read from that selection, you see a flat array, but if you write to it (as above) then it modifies the original array.

Also, I explicitly cast `den` to `double` because if  both operands were integers there would by horror.

**Update:** It seems you should cast `den`, if you cast `num` it will still work, but you get a warning.  Safest thing is to cast both.

Comment: Thanks, but it does give me a RuntimeWarning, that I have to catch.

Comment: In python 2.7, if `num` and `den` are integer it won't work (you get `0` instead of `inf` and `nan`. In python 3 you don't need the cast

Comment: you don't have to catch warnings. They just warn you and don't interrupt the execution. Of course you can catch it if you want. [numpy.seterr](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html#numpy.seterr) should help you getting rid of the warning

Comment: Umm.. sorry, I had meant that I don't want the user to know there is a warning.

Comment: In Python2 I get no warning as long as I make sure that the argument is an array of doubles.  @Fransesco how do numpy arrays behave in python3?  Do they use the exact representation or does it automatically give you floating point?

Comment: num and den are always arrays of floats. So that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: in python3 when doing division the cast is automatic: 3/2=1.5. If you want rounding you do 3//2=1

Comment: @Manoj: either try to play with numpy.seterr or use [`try/except'](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) to hide the warning

Comment: @Manoj, my (updated) version which casts `den` works for me in both Python 2.7.3 and 3.2.3.  as @Fransesco says, there should be some error setting in numpy that you can use.  And try the explicit cast anyway - it's always nice to check your assumptions.

Comment: OK the fragment now temporarily disable the error message, just while the division is happening (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519237/python-how-to-avoid-runtimewarning-in-function-definition).  I hope that works for you @Manoj!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a nested np.where statement

```
numpy.where(denom !=0, 1 - numel/denom, np.where(numel != 0, 0, 1))
```