# numpy: Efficiently avoid 0s when taking log(matrix)

Tags: numpy

```
from numpy import *

m = array([[1,0],
           [2,3]])
```

I would like to compute the element-wise `log2(m)`, but only in the places where `m` is not 0. In those places, I would like to have 0 as a result.

I am now fighting against:

```
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log2
```

---

**Try 1: using `where`**

```
res = where(m != 0, log2(m), 0)
```

which computes me the correct result, but I still get logged a `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log2`. It looks like (and syntactically it is quite obvious) numpy still computes `log2(m)` on the full matrix and only afterwards `where` picks the values to keep.

I would like to avoid this warning.

---

**Try 2: using masks**

```
from numpy import ma

res = ma.filled(log2(ma.masked_equal(m, 0)), 0)
```

Sure masking away the zeros will prevent `log2` to get applied to them, won't it? Unfortunately not: We still get `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log2`.

Even though the matrix is masked, `log2` still seems to be applied to every element.

---

**How can I efficiently compute the element-wise log of a numpy array without getting division-by-zero warnings?**

- Of course I could temporarily disable the logging of these warnings using `seterr`, but that doesn't look like a clean solution.
- And sure a double *for* loop would help with treating 0s specially, but defeats the efficiency of numpy.

Any ideas?

Comment: As you prefer. Notice however that using masked arrays is less efficient then disabling momentarily the error. And disabling the specific 'divide by zero' warning does not disable the other problem with calculating the log of a number, which is negative input. That case is captured as an 'invalid value' warning.

Comment: On the other hand, using masked arrays captures the two errors as the same, and may lead you to not notice an error in the input. In other words, a negative number in the input is treated like a zero, and will give zero as a result.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

We can use masked arrays for this:

```
>>> from numpy import *
>>> m = array([[1,0], [2,3]])
>>> x = ma.log(m)
>>> print x.filled(0)
[[ 0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.69314718  1.09861229]]
```

Comment: `q=array([0.0,1.0])` and `log(q.astype(float))` raises the RuntimeWarning on my machine. As well, numpy stops warning me about the division by error after the first warning in ipython. Maybe you were mislead by that?

Comment: @flebool: Haha, you're right, I was misled.  I used regular Python (2.7.6) and it too stopped warning after the first try.  Oh well, I'll edit my answer shortly.

Comment: Ah, `ma` has its own `log2`! Great.

Answer (score 39):

Another option is to use the [`where` parameter of numpy's ufuncs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html#optional-keyword-arguments):

```
m = np.array([[1., 0], [2, 3]])
res = np.log2(m, out=np.zeros_like(m), where=(m!=0))
```

No `RuntimeWarning` is raised, and zeros are introduced where the log is not computed.

Comment: `out=np.zeros_like(m)` is quite important. The output might look alright when you forget this, but you will be using uninitialized memory.

Comment: @bers Are you sure? How come the uninitialized memory is all zeros (at least on initial testing)?

Comment: But you're right, it does say so in [the docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.log.html).

Comment: @Casimir I have wondered the same a couple of times. I guess this is what "undefined behavior" means in standards - it may be working, but you must not rely on it. Pretty dangerous in my opinion. For the record, `import numpy as np; m=np.zeros((1000,)); sum(np.log2(m, where=(m!=0)))` gives 0 on Python 3.8.10 on WSL Ubuntu, but 4.53139328456056e-308 on Python 3.10.7 on Windows 10 (same system).

Comment: If m is of an Integer dtype, e.g. int64, the above gives a TypeError of 'same_kind' casting rule. To fix it simply add dtype float to the zeros_like function: `np.zeros_like(m, dtype='float64')`. This ensures that the zeros have the same data type as the log function outputs.

Answer (score 27):

Simply disable the warning for that computation:

```
from numpy import errstate,isneginf,array

m = array([[1,0],[2,3]])
with errstate(divide='ignore'):
    res = log2(m)
```

And then you can postprocess the `-inf` if you want:

```
res[isneginf(res)]=0
```

EDIT: I put here some comments about the other option, which is using masked arrays, posted in the other answer. You should opt for disabling the error for two reasons:

1) Using masked arrays is by far less efficient then disabling momentarily the error, and you asked for efficiency.

2) Disabling the specific 'divide by zero' warning does NOT disable the other problem with calculating the log of a number, which is negative input. Negative input is captured as an 'invalid value' warning, and you will have to deal with it.

On the other hand, using masked arrays captures the two errors as the same, and will lead you to not notice a negative number in the input. In other words, a negative number in the input is treated like a zero, and will give zero as a result. This is not what you asked.

3) As a last point and as a personal opinion, disabling the warning is very readable, it is obvious what the code is doing and makes it more mantainable. In that respect, I find this solution cleaner then using masked arrays.

Comment: use `with np.errstate(divide='ignore'):
  res = log2(m)` instead of calling `seterr` twice: you cannot forget to disable ignoring after your calculation, and it will reset to the previous setting afterwards, too (which @gg349 doesn't atm): <https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.errstate.html>
(yes, I'm very late with this :)

Comment: @azrdev, absolutely! I have implemented your proposal above.

Answer (score 9):

The masked array solution and the solution that disables the warning are both fine.  For variety, here's another that uses [`scipy.special.xlogy`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.xlogy.html).  `np.sign(m)` is given as the `x` argument, so `xlogy` returns 0 wherever `np.sign(m)` is 0.
The result is divided by `np.log(2)` to give the base-2 logarithm.

```
In [4]: from scipy.special import xlogy

In [5]: m = np.array([[1, 0], [2, 3]])

In [6]: xlogy(np.sign(m), m) / np.log(2)
Out[6]: 
array([[ 0.       ,  0.       ],
       [ 1.       ,  1.5849625]])
```

Answer (score 3):

## Problem

Questions: [Feb 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21752989/10450752), [May 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10519237/10450752)

For an array containing `zeros` or `negatives` we get the respective errors.

```
y = np.log(x)
# RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
# RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log
```

## Solution

[markroxor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51407559/10450752) suggests `np.clip`, in my example this creates a horizontal floor.  [gg349](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21753388/10450752) and others use `np.errstate` and `np.seterr`, I think these are clunky and does not solve the problem.  As a note `np.complex` doesn't work for zeros.  [user3315095](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21807038/10450752) uses indexing `p=0<x`, and [NumPy.log](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log.html) has this functionality built in, `where`/`out`.  [mdeff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52209380/10450752) demonstrates this, but replaces the `-inf` with `0` which for me was insufficient, and doesn't solve for negatives.

I suggest `0<x` and `np.nan` (or if needed `np.NINF`/`-np.inf`).

```py
y = np.log(x, where=0<x, out=np.nan*x)
```

[John Zwinck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21753270/10450752) uses mask matrix `np.ma.log` this works but is computationally slower, try App:timeit.

## Example

```
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 300)

# y = np.log(x)                         # Old
y = np.log(x, where=0<x, out=np.nan*x)  # New

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

#### App:timeit

Time Comparison for `mask` and `where`

```
import numpy as np
import time
def timeit(fun, xs):
    t = time.time()
    for i in range(len(xs)):
        fun(xs[i])
    print(time.time() - t)

xs = np.random.randint(-10,+10, (1000,10000))
timeit(lambda x: np.ma.log(x).filled(np.nan), xs)
timeit(lambda x: np.log(x, where=0<x, out=np.nan*x), xs)
```

Answer (score 2):

What about the following

```
from numpy import *
m=array((-1.0,0.0,2.0))
p=m > 0.0
print 'positive=',p
print m[p]
res=zeros_like(m)
res[p]=log(m[p])
print res
```

Comment: This also works! I like the `ma` solution a bit better because it allows me to write a side-effect free expression, and it composes nicely with other functions from `ma`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like - 
`m = np.clip(m, 1e-12, None)` to avoid the log(0) error. This will set the lower bound to `1e-12`.

Answer (score 0):

Just operate on the nonzero elements:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(10)
x[x!=0] = np.log2(x[x!=0])
print(x)
```

---

Bonus. Compute the Kullback-Leibler divergence while avoiding zeroes in the division:

```
def kldiv(p,q):
    x = np.divide(p[(p!=0)&(q!=0)],q[(p!=0)&(q!=0)])
    return np.sum(p[(p!=0)&(q!=0)] * np.log(x))
```

Comment: This is the same approach as [@user3315095 suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21807038/263061) 8 years ago to this thread (using `m > 0.0` instead of `x != 0`).