# pandas: Efficiently avoid 0s when taking log of cells in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I want to take the log of each cell in a very sparse pandas DataFrame and must avoid the 0s. At first I was checking for 0s with a lambda function, then I thought it might be faster to replace the many 0s with NaNs. I got some inspiration from this [closely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21752989/numpy-efficiently-avoid-0s-when-taking-logmatrix), and tried using a "mask." Is there a better way?

```python
# first approach
# 7.61 s ± 1.46 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
def get_log_1(df):
    return df.applymap(
        lambda x: math.log(x) if x != 0 else 0)

# second approach (faster!)
# 5.36 s ± 968 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
def get_log_2(df):
    return (df
            .replace(0, np.nan)
            .applymap(math.log)
            .replace(np.nan, 0))

# third apprach (even faster!!)
# 4.76 s ± 941 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
def get_log_3(df):
    return (df
            .mask(df <= 0)
            .applymap(math.log)
            .fillna(0))
```

Comment: Is possible add `df` for test?

Comment: The `df` I'm using has `shape` (31064, 323) and is ~90% 0s. I think this generates something similar? `np.put(np.zeros((30000, 300)), range(0, 3000), 1); df = pd.DataFrame(a).sample(frac=1)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possible solution is use [`numpy.log`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log.html):

```
print (np.log(df.mask(df <=0)).fillna(0))
```

Or pure `numpy`:

```
df1= pd.DataFrame(np.ma.log(df.values).filled(0), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
```

Comment: Wow! So much faster, and cleaner! Using `math.log` instead of `np.log` was a rookie move on my part.

Comment: @DustinMichels - Can you add timings to question?

Comment: 341 ms ± 7.08 ms the first way, 35.6 ns ± 5.57 ns the second way (measured with the Ipython `%timeit` magic)