# How to get sound level (dB) of audio in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wonder that how to get sound pressure level in dB. The input should be the signal from the microphone of PC (real-time audio signal). The output is the real-time sound pressure level of input signal. This is my simple code.

```
import pyaudio
import numpy as np
import wave
from threading import Thread
from pysine import sine
import math
import time


def print_sound():

   CHUNK = 1024
   FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
   CHANNELS = 1
   RATE = 44100
   pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
   stream = pa.open(format=FORMAT,
                     channels=CHANNELS,
                     rate=RATE,
                     input=True,
                     frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
   buffer = []
   while True:
      string_audio_data = stream.read(CHUNK) 
      audio_data = np.frombuffer(string_audio_data, np.int16)
      volume_norm = np.linalg.norm(audio_data)*10
      dfft = 10.*np.log10(abs(np.fft.rfft(audio_data)))
      print(int(volume_norm))
print_sound()
```

and this error is
`Warning (from warnings module): File "C:\Users\Admin\1.py", line 27 dfft = 10.*np.log10(abs(np.fft.rfft(audio_data))) RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log10`

Comment: How does a level of 0 translate in dB? Here is probably the source of your error.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21752989/numpy-efficiently-avoid-0s-when-taking-logmatrix

Answer (score 0):

As @Thierry pointed out above it will not be possible to get a dB SPL answer without calibrating your speaker/microphone system with actual measurements. It will be possible (as it seems you've done with your code snippet) to report *relative* levels.

These are the minimum requirements you need to report absolute dB SPL:

1. dynamic range of your ADC (max/min voltage range) - what is the loudest sound that can be captured by the ADC of the computer.
2. the sensitivity of your microphone (mV/Pa). For a sound of X Pascals pressure, how many mV (or sample-related measurement) are produced
3. speaker calibration - given an input signal with Y rms, how many Pa (and thus dB SPL) will the output sound be?