# How to avoid "RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide" in NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to avoid the warning `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide` in NumPy.

I thought I could do:

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([0.0])
print A.dtype
with np.errstate(divide='ignore'):
    B=A/A
print B
```

but this gives:

```
float64
./t.py:9: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide
  B=A/A
[ nan]
```

If I replace `B=A/A` with `np.float64(1.0) / 0.0` it gives no warning.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python : How to avoid RuntimeWarning in function definition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519237/python-how-to-avoid-runtimewarning-in-function-definition)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to set `invalid` rather than `divide`:

```
with np.errstate(invalid='ignore'):
                 ^^^^^^^
```